# modal window from JavaScript, not opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am using Javascript to generate html like this

```
for (var count = 0; count < data.length; count++) {
            var provider = data[count].Provider;
            var icon_provider = provider.toLowerCase(); 
            html=html+"some code here";               
            html = html + "<div class=\"icon\"><i class=\"fa fa-" + icon_provider + "\"></i></div><a href=\"#\" class=\"small-box-footer\" onclick=\"myFunction()\">More info <i class=\"fa fa-arrow-circle-right\"></i></a></div></div>";
        }
```

I am calling a function called `"myFunction"` when `clicked`.

```
function myFunction() {
$('#myModal').modal('show')
```

}

all this is in a indexInvoice.js file.

Now i have a `index page` which has all the scripts.

```
 <!--javascript for the index page-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/IndexInvoice.js"></script>

<!--jQuery for modal window from bootstrap-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#myInput').focus()
})
</script>
```

and the `div` where html is generated through javascript(from indexInvoice.js) is this.

```
<div id="row1" class="row">
            <!--Modal window-->
                <div class="modal fade" data-target="#myModal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                this is modal window
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.row -->
```

The div has a std modal window code from bootstrap.

Now the Issue is when I `click` the that element, I am not able to get the modal window. Although when a put a `alert` in `myFunction` it shows the `alert`.

Comment: Try `$('#myModal').modal('show')`

Comment: @haim770 its like that only.error in typing.still not working.

Answer (score 1):

it should be `$('#myModal').modal("show");` check the double quotes

Comment: @Alexander yes i agree either of single or double quotes we need to use

Comment: have you included bootstrap scripts?